# Why doesn’t my jQuery change the class of an element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseover, addclass

Sorry if this question is overly specific to my own concept but I’m totally stuck. I’m trying to have the title of the user’s current page turn orange when you hover over the page’s name in the navigation. In other words, when you hover over the **li** element who’s value is “Homepage”, the **h1** element who’s value is “Homepage” will turn orange. I’m trying to use the **.addClass** and **.removeClass** methods to change the turn the **h1** element orange, but have had no luck so far. When I hover over the li element, it’s like it doesn’t even recognize my pointer is there. All other jQuery effects work on the site. 
I’ve included my complete jQuery and my abbreviated HTML and CSS below — your help is greatly appreciated!

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #328cff;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.95;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#header ul {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
#header ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 20px 0 20px;
  height: 31px;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
  transition: text-shadow 0.5s ease;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#header ul li.active {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 10005;
}
#header ul a li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#header ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#header ul a:hover {
  color: #ff9100;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #328cff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
  z-index: 30;
}
.orange {
  color: #ff9100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("li.active").mouseover(function() {
        $("h1#title").addClass("orange");
      });
      $("li.active").mouseout(function() {
        $("h1#title").removeClass("orange");
      });
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">Home</li>
      <a href="page2.html">
        <li>Section 508 Compliance</li>
      </a>
      <a href="page3.html">
        <li>Table</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h1 id="title">Home</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: An aside: the "h1" in the selector is superfluous. IDs are unique, so saying "#title" already is 100% specific.

Comment: [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the **specificity** of your CSS. The colour declaration made using `#title` overrides that made using `.orange`, both of which applies to `<h1>`. Instead, simply modify your CSS:

```
#title.orange {
  color: #ff9100;
}
```

See snippet below:

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #328cff;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.95;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#header ul {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
#header ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 20px 0 20px;
  height: 31px;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
  transition: text-shadow 0.5s ease;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#header ul li.active {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 10005;
}
#header ul a li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#header ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#header ul a:hover {
  color: #ff9100;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #328cff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
  z-index: 30;
}
#title.orange {
  color: #ff9100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("li.active").mouseover(function() {
        $("h1#title").addClass("orange");
      });
      $("li.active").mouseout(function() {
        $("h1#title").removeClass("orange");
      });
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">Home</li>
      <a href="page2.html">
        <li>Section 508 Compliance</li>
      </a>
      <a href="page3.html">
        <li>Table</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h1 id="title">Home</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#title` CSS selector has a greater CSS specificity than the `.orange` selector so it will always have precedence even when the orange class is present.

You can fix this by changing your orange CSS rule to this:

```
#title.orange {
  color: #ff9100;
}
```

This gives this new rule a greater CSS specificity than just the #title rule when the orange class is present so it will take over.